# using curl to interact with REST API - error: "Content not allowed in prolog"

Tags: rest, curl

I am sending the following curl command from terminal in Mac OSX:

```
curl -d "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=1AD….4&INPUT_DATA=TestData.xml" http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/sdpapi/request/
```

I am getting back the response:

FailedError when performing - ADD_REQUEST - Content is not allowed in prolog.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Operation>
<Details>
<requester>Me</requester>
<subject>Test</subject>
<description>Testing curl input</description>
</Details>
</Operation>
```

I have checked and my xml file is indeed a UTF-8 file.  I can tell from google searches that this most likely has to do with my encoding, however, I can't find how to fix it.
I've also tried saving the xml file as ANSI on my pc, xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Operation>
<Details>
<requester>Me</requester>
<subject>Test</subject>
<description>Testing curl input</description>
</Details>
</Operation>
```

I downloaded Notepad++ and checked the encoding, which is UTF8 with no BOM.

I am still getting the same error.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Updated 9/19 to add:
In addition to everything I've tried in the comments below, I've also tried this:

```
curl -d "OPERATION_NAME=ADD_REQUEST&TECHNICIAN_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&INPUT_DATA=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Operation><Details><requester>Me</requester><subject>Test</subject><description>Testing curl input</description></Details></Operation>" http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/sdpapi/request/
```

The error I'm getting now is: "Error when performing - ADD_REQUEST - The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string."

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I tried this with "UTF" replaced with "utf"  Still getting the same error message.

Comment: So it looks like the error might be that it is not finding the xml file.  If I pass in a bogus filename I get the same error.  I've tried /user/filename.xml (I'm on a mac) but it still does not find it...any suggestions?

Comment: I've also tried this on my pc, indicating the full path to the xml file...same error.  What am I missing???

Comment: Do you ever feel like you are talking to yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` with  `<?xml version=%221.0%22 encoding=%22utf-8%22?>`

It is now working.